# List of included files in the pdf on titlepage

Tags: itemize, include

I would like to have a (itemized) list of the files I have included in the pdf which is defined in `\includeonly{}`.

My approach ist not working at all, since a lot of manual work is needed for each included file, there is a `missing \item` in the `itemize` environment and it’s methodologically incorrect since the `bools` are always set to `true` in each file; it doesn’t matter if it included or not.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,etoolbox}
\newbool{chapter01}
\newbool{chapter02}
\newbool{chapter03}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter01.tex}
    \chapter{This is chapter 01}
    \booltrue{chapter01}
    \blindtext[3]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapter02.tex}
    \chapter{This is chapter 02}
    \booltrue{chapter02}
    \blindtext[3]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapter03.tex}
    \chapter{This is chapter 03}
    \booltrue{chapter03}
    \blindtext[3]
\end{filecontents}

\includeonly{%
 chapter01,
% chapter02,
 chapter03
}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    This PDF contains:
    \begin{itemize}
     \ifbool{chapter01}{\item Chapter 01}{}
     \ifbool{chapter02}{\item Chapter 02}{}
     \ifbool{chapter03}{\item Chapter 03}{}
    \end{itemize}
\end{titlepage}
\include{chapter01}
\include{chapter02}
\include{chapter03}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\includeonly` macro creates a comma separated list of the files called `\@partlist`. So all we need to do is create a macro to process that list and output it in the way you like. The order of the list will be the same order exactly as that in the `\includeonly` command.  Sorting the list would require more overhead.

Here's an example (updated to deal with underscores in filenames).

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_3.tex}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\end{filecontents}
\includeonly{\jobname_1, \jobname_2}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\filename}{\urlstyle{rm}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listincluded}{%
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item \filename{##1.tex}}
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\@partlist}
\end{enumerate}
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
\begin{center}
\bfseries List of Included Files
\end{center}
\listincluded
}
\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\include{\jobname1}
\include{\jobname2}
\include{\jobname3}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: How to cope with filenames which contain `_`? I get the `invalid in math mode`-error.

Comment: Don't use filenames with `_`. :)  I'll see what I can do, though.

Comment: yes, you are right. I see that it is a problem. But I am wondering what is easier, renaming 50+ files or finding a solution :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LukasCB Well renaming 50 files is one line of `bash`.  So definitely easier.

Comment: @LukasCB I've updated the answer. It now deals with underscores.